# Flutter Build failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' while building to connect to Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image]    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> File 'C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar' specified for property 'androidJar' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       133.3s (!)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: I've added the flutter doctor. and also I've checked my AndroidManifest.xml and it has no permission so i added it also. but still same result.

Comment: i changed my SDK Version and fixed the first problem but now it's not communicating with my Firebase.

Comment: This isn't a troubleshooting forum. Please remove the question if it's resolved by fixing a type (the SDK version). Ask a new one if you have additional questions. But first, See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).